# Why are edge fields in undolators necessary to comply with Maxwell?

Tags: magnetic-fields, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

In our lecture scripts there is a paragraph about the magnetic field of an undulator:

"Its [the undulators] magentic field can be described by
\begin{equation}
 \vec{B}\equiv-B_0 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \sin k_u z  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $k_u$ is the undulator wave number
defined by $_ = 2_$. Note that this definition injures Maxwell’s equation [$\nabla\cdot \vec B = 0$], but this does not
play a role here since „compensating“ edge fields exist that can be neglected for this definition."

How exactly does this B-field violate $\nabla\cdot \vec B = 0$?

\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot \vec B &= \partial_x \cdot 0 + \partial_y (-B_0 \sin k_u z)+\partial_z \cdot 0 \\
&= 0  
\end{align}
What am I missing? If the undulator was infinitely big, there would be no edge fields but the B-field would still be there. Then how can it violate Maxwell's equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxwell laws prescribe that the magnetic field lines must be closed, closing them at infinity is kind of a math trick. While you are right saying that the field satisfies $\nabla\cdot \vec B = 0$, such field cannot be produced by a piece of hardware in the real world.

For the sake of the beam dynamics that is a good approximation at the center of the undulator, but as soon as you move away in the x or y directions, other components have to appear.